# Grouping rows using a pre calculated number

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as below:

```
id name address batch
1  t1   addr1    
2  t2   addr2 
3  t3   addr3
4  t4   addr4
5  t5   addr5
6  t6   addr6
```

I need a sql to populate the batch column using a predetermined batch size. So for example, if the batch size is calculated to be 2, then the table would be as follows:

```
id name address batch
1  t1   addr1   1    
2  t2   addr2   1
3  t3   addr3   2
4  t4   addr4   2
5  t5   addr5   3
6  t6   addr6   3
```

So, since the batch size is 2, we assign a batch starting at 1 for that many number of rows (in this case 2)

Can anybody help me with the sql?

Thanks.

Comment: is your `id` column always sequential? then @dherre65's solution will work, otherwise use `row_number` as @GordonLinoff suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*,
       floor((row_number() over (order by id - 1))/2)
from t;
```

The "2" is the batch size.

Answer (score 1):

You could divide the id by 2 and then ceil it; 1 would be 0.5 but ceiled = 1, 2 would be 1, so that's batch 1. Etc.

```
select
  id, name,
  ceil(id::decimal / 2) as batch_nr

from batch

order by id;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/ca419/1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `floor` function just use ranking function :

```
select b.*
      (1 + (row_number() over (order by id)-1) / 2) as batch
from batch b;
```